# Issue running react native project in Linix & Mac

Tags: linux, react-native, macos

I tried to run my react native project "react-native": "0.72.6", in linux.
It showing me Errors stating that android studio and platform tools not found.
I am using "react-native": "0.72.3" in  another project that is working fine without any issue.I tried all the troubleshooting steps but that didn't work to me. Any solution to run in linux with 0.72.6 ?

I tried checking the ANDROID_HOME and Emulatiors and react native doctor also.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I having the same issue. what i was done simply laughable in my opinion. i just have changed android folder permission then magically it worked.

here the code to change file permission.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./android/
```

execute above line of code from **project folder** then tray to run project again it will worked.

**tested in mac m1 and ubuntu**

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I am able to run the project now in my linux machine.